# Optional path segment in Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey

I've searched for hours on this and haven't quite got it right.

An API on a project I'm working on is not versioned (`/controller/blah`), so we want to introduce versioning. For example, we have a class with `@Path("/controller")` associated to it. Naturally to avoid API breakage, this now has to support either `/` or `/v1/`, so the following would be valid:

```
/controller/blah
/v1/controller/blah
```

I feel there must be an easy solution to this that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just 1 question: `/controller/blah` and `/v1/controller/blah` would reach the same method?

Comment: @JavierFromMadrid you got it :) they're the same version, just an alias so that people can adopt the /v1 safely in their own time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Filter to redirect those requests which matched certain pattern  (on your case **/v1/***).

Your **Filter** should look like:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "MyCustomFilter")
public class MyCustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
            FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest)arg0).getRequestURI();
            //Take into account thet the url here would be the complete url. I just put an example taking into account
            //your application name is JAX-RS_tutorial
            String redirect = url.substring("/JAX-RS_tutorial/v1".length(), url.length());
            arg0.getRequestDispatcher(redirect).forward(arg0, arg1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And then on **web.xml**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyCustomFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myapplication.filter.MyCustomFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyCustomFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v1/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**UPDATE**

Really you just need to add new *url-pattern* for your *servlet-mapping*. So just need on **web.xml**:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v1/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Sweet, I'll take a shot at this and get back to you - is a filter the only way to do this? No cool regex on the paths etc?

Comment: In fact you do not need Filter, just need to add new _url-pattern_ entry on your _servlet-maping_, just checked :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with option regex to prefix your URI.

The below path will match both `/foo` & `/v1/foo`

```
@Path("/{ver : (v1/)?}foo")
```

Comment: Although this is correct, the original question was to apply it to all routes - not having to supply the Regex on every path.

Comment: I believe you can use the regex on the RestController top level mapping as well. And all paths will inherit the version prefix from there.