# Jax-rs/Jersey regex path rules clashing

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have this path rules with Jersey annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("{format:([^/]+?)?}")
```

that it matchs with www.site.com/it or www.site.com , and that's perfect for me. Now, I want to add a new rule that matchs with:
www.site.com/it/search or www.site.com/search.
I have tried this one:

```
@GET
@Path("{format:([^/]+?)?}/search")
```

but actually the first rule got fired, how can I do to exclude from the first one some strings (like search and others one) or as opposite solutions, limit the optional path to some specific values, like it,en,fr, etc....
Thank you

Comment: Is `www.site.com/search` your path parameter?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin /search is my path parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try for first endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/{format: \\w*}")
```

And this for second endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/{format: \\w*}/search")
```

Comment: is messing up with static content, no images,css are loaded, must clash with other paths.

Comment: You could add also language as a query parameter. Or you could limit language regex to 2-3 chars.

Comment: I would like to avoid the solutions as a query parameter. Can I gently ask you a solution with regex limited to 2 characters? I tried with no much success! Thank you!

Comment: ```@Path("/{format: ^\\w{2}$}")```  this will match only when there are exactly 2 chars

Comment: Now, looks completely broken. even www.site.com/en doesn't work. How can I add a limit of two chracter to this regular expressions? {format:([^/]+?)?}This one was actually much closer to work

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I found this solution:  [Optional path segment in Jersey JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773874/optional-path-segment-in-jersey-jax-rs)

Really you just need to add new url-pattern for your servlet-mapping. 
So just need on web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v1/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```